# Spring Data JPA and Hibernate for creation of sessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sessionfactory

Spring data jpa is an abstraction over Jpa and Spring data jpa by default implements Hibernate ORM . for using hibernate we create sessionFactory. but why we are not creating session factory when working with spring data JPA?

Answer (score 1):

The question mixes up a number of concepts related to Spring, Hibernate, and JPA, let me try to untangle them:

> Spring data jpa is an abstraction over Jpa

In a way, I guess.

> Spring data jpa by default implements Hibernate ORM

Umm, nope. Spring Data uses Hibernate as the provider for the JPA API.

> for using hibernate we create sessionFactory

Well, yes and no. Hibernate can be used in two ways:

- by interacting with its proprietary API, i.e. using `SessionFactory`, `Session` etc.
- by interacting with the JPA API it implements, i.e. `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager`

Spring Data JPA is doing the latter.

> why we are not creating session factory when working with spring data JPA?

Because Spring Data requires an `EntityManagerFactory`. It does not use `SessionFactory`.

In Spring, this usually means you need to configure a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. When using Spring Boot, this is done for you automatically - see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration.java):

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean({ LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class, EntityManagerFactory.class })
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder factoryBuilder) {
        Map<String, Object> vendorProperties = getVendorProperties();
        customizeVendorProperties(vendorProperties);
        return factoryBuilder.dataSource(this.dataSource).packages(getPackagesToScan()).properties(vendorProperties)
                .mappingResources(getMappingResources()).jta(isJta()).build();
    }
```

What the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean({ LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class, EntityManagerFactory.class })` annotation does is it creates a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` *only if* you haven't provided such a bean yourself. This means you can provide your own `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and it will be used instead, if you want.

Also, if you were to use Spring Data JPA without Spring Boot, you would **have to** provide a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` yourself or else Spring Data wouldn't work.